# tsFresh - The given column for the id is not present in the data

Tags: python, tsfresh

How do I solve the attribute error:

```
The given column for the id is not present in the data
```

when the `column_id` is 'ID' in the pandas dataframe used as input for the tsfresh "extract_features" function?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is `ID` is level of `MultiIndex`, so need convert all levels to columns first by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: i added this line and may I ask how to solve this error 'cannot insert level_0, already exists'

Comment: what is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 506 entries, (11, 003d25e3fac5a1d2aa4ba502ffb77b5b, F, 67, SINGAPOREAN, 24/05/17, LIFE1, 67) to (13, ff575837be18088c0d64ae00a0228621, M, 38, SINGAPOREAN, 16/05/17, LIFE1,HIV, 38)
Data columns (total 62 columns):
Albumin                         506 non-null float64
Alkaline Phosphatase            506 non-null float64